# when I refresh the screen or Add Item ,the Listview current item go to the top.How to do it?

Tags: android, listview

when I refresh the screen or Add Item ,the Listview current item go to the top.How to do it?
I want to do that when I add one item or refresh the screen ,the current item go to the top?
who can give me a idea?